# What is the expected query response performance for BigQuery when querying over 400 million rows form multiple sharded tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have noticed consistently slow BigQuery performance (between 30 seconds to 1 minute response time) when query more 400 million rows from multiple sharded tables.

I have run the queries 3 times in different time of day (afternoon, late evening and morning), notice response time has been consistently slow.  The query uses a group-by string field that may have a lot of unique values and then sort by sum of another integer value in descending order and finally return only the top 10.

I have done performance timing testing on same schema and same query but storing all the data in one to five tables and noticed performance was always under 10 seconds.

What is the expected response time for querying dataset with 400 millions to 2 billions rows sharded in 7 to 90 sharded tables?  Can sharding data in more tables cause slower query performance?  FYI, each of the of the shard table has at least 24 million to 144 million rows.  They are not very small tables.

Answer (score 0):

The expected query performance depends highly on your query. Are you using GROUP EACH BY in your query?

The number of tables your data is sharded into shouldn't have much effect on query performance unless the number of tables is very large (in the hundreds or thousands). If you are seeing performance differences, then something may be wrong. Would you mind sharing either the queries you are running or the project and job ids of the queries that were fast vs the queries that were slow?

Comment: I have been using group each by. Should I avoid using it for sharded tables?  project id is atbflow.  Here is the fast bqjob_r3d7cf424fae4ce4b_0000013ed3ba2970_1.  Here is one of the slow query from this morning run: bqjob_r7be8afd6b1a257e3_0000013ed78bc6ae_1.

Comment: Likely because the group by field is string with a lot of unique values, I often get error "Resources exceeded during query execution. The query contained a GROUP BY operator, consider using GROUP
EACH BY instead." if I just use group by.